# Create folder in symfony root that is not controlled by symfony

Tags: symfony

I want to create `http://localhost/Symfony/temp/`.

In temp will be a basic index.html and some images. If I create the folder right now and put the index.html file in /temp/ I get a 404.

How do I get a normal response from `http://localhost/Symfony/temp/index.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests going to `temp/` are being caught by Symfony's default `.htaccess`. You'll have to add following:

```
# allow access to temp
RewriteRule ^temp.* - [QSA,L]
```

If you want it to work even with `app_dev.php` just change it to `^[app_dev.php/]*temp.*`.

But I'm more interested why do you want to do that in root directory and not in static files directory (eg. web/static/temp). You wouldn't need to mess around with `.htaccess` and you'd be able to link to such images with `asset(...)`.

Comment: Because I'm a total Symfony n00b. I did figure out the solution I was looking for, but yours is more graceful. Thank you. I'll post my version for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I eventually came up with.

All I did was create a .htaccess file in /temp/ and inserted:

```
allow from all
```

Since I was getting a 404 error and all the other symfony folders had a .htaccess with

```
deny from all
```

I reversed engineered an answer.

Hope this helps someone else.